# Buffered Reader read() return char comparison

Tags: java, buffer, bufferedreader

I am using the Buffered reader to read the file character by character and javadoc mention it returns

```
"The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached
".
```

Now i want to compare the character of this read() method and skip some undesired characters from the stream(appending the useful ones to StringBuilder for further use). My Confusion is does the read() returns the decimal value or Hex values ?

**should i compare** `int return < 32` or `int return < 0x20`

Which is the correct way of doing it ?

Comment: They are the exact same value, `32 == 0x20` , so do as you prefer.

Comment: Thank you, Would it be always same scenario ? or just for the integers i would appreciate if you point me to some article somewhere to read, i know converting both into binary both are same value but what the actual return of Buffered reader ?

Comment: They already were the same value. There is no such thing as a hex value. There are just values. Hex is only a notation. Decimal is another. 0x20 = 32 (decimal), always and everywhere, on paper and inside a computer.